# Erro Carregar varias páginas em site php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho um site em PHP no qual tenho de carregar varias paginas.Porem só uma vez. O que esta acontecendo é a sobreposição de telas com varias inclusões.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>MAPAS</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Detalhes</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Mapas</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Cadastrar Devices</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Alerta</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fadee">
        <?php require_once "paginas/detalhes.php"; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <?php require_once "paginas/mapas.php"; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <?php require_once "paginas/cadastrodivices.php"; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
        <?php require_once "paginas/alerta.php"; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Erro da Tela**
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro Alex?

Comment: A estrutura da tela MApas esta presente em todas as abas..

Comment: Quero apenas carregar uma vez cada estruturas...ou seja apenas carregar uma vez cada aba com as estruturas delas.

Comment: Será porque não estão lá, mas atrás umas das outras? Vê o codigo fonte da página para ver se estão lá

Comment: Sim..o erro no include ou require.. Preciso carregar uma vez e não carregar mais. Acha que usar ajax aqui ou Jquery ??

Comment: Jquery/Javascript, tens de delegar o evento click nas abas e fazer aparecer a secção respetiva, vou colocar um exemplo simples com jquery em baixo. Mas aparentemente estás a usar bootstrap, já devia funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema usando o plugin do **[jquery Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)**
Com ele abas carregar uma vez apenas cada pagina .php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="paginas/detalhes.php">Detalhes</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/mapas.php">Mapas</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/cadastrodivices.php">Cadastrar Divices</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/alerta.php">Alerta</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```